# TableView does not populate JSON array in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, json, uitableview, swift3

I've read a lot of related questions here, but am still struggling with populating my tableview. I get the result from the print(firstname) and print(lastname) in the console. But nothing appears in the tableview.
The Table view has a Prototype cell with identifier BasicCell.
Any idea why the table is not populating?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
let URL_GET_PERSONAGE = "http://somesite.net/somescript.php"
var firstnames: [String] = []
var lastnames: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: URL_GET_PERSONAGE)
    do{
        let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
        if let arrJSON = allContacts["teams"] as? NSArray{
            for index in 0..<arrJSON.count{
                let aObject = arrJSON[index] as? [String : AnyObject]
                firstnames.append(aObject?["fname"] as! String)
                lastnames.append(aObject?["lname"] as! String)

            }
            print(firstnames)
            print(lastnames)
            listTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    catch {
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.firstnames.count;
    }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell! = self.listTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasicCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell!
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.firstnames[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}    
}
```

Comment: Have you attach the datasource and delegate to viewController in storyboard

Comment: @Mandeep Singh 
 
I did ctrl+drag listTableView to the ViewController and selected datasource and delegate. When I run it, I get a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error in AppDelegate and the console gives `[TestSwift.ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa3b7408850 2017-01-20 10:51:46.430 TestSwift[2199:635830] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestSwift.ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa3b7408850' *** First throw call stack:...`

Comment: Can you add the breakpoint to numberOfRowsInSection check whether the crash will be in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection or the crash will be in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Can you please check it.